# dismissModalViewController not working when there is no internet connection MPMoviePlayerViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller

I have MPMoviePlayerViewController that I call using `presentModalViewController:animated:`. When there is an error (no internet connection) I want to dismiss it. However, `dismissModalViewController` seems to not work in this case.

```
- (void)movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{      
     NSLog(@"MOVIE FINISH CALL");

    // Obtain the reason why the movie playback finished
    NSNumber *finishReason = [[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey];    
    // Dismiss the view controller ONLY when the reason is not "playback ended"

    if ([finishReason intValue] != MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
    {     

        NSlog(@"Check go here");
        MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];     
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                      object:moviePlayer];        
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];        
    }
}



- (void)playPodcastRadio:(NSString *) urlRadio
{
     // Initialize the movie player view controller with a video URL string

    MPMoviePlayerViewController* mediaPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlRadio]];
    mediaPlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown; 

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:mediaPlayer name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:mediaPlayer.moviePlayer];

    // Register this class as an observer instead    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  object:mediaPlayer.moviePlayer];

    mediaPlayer.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    // Present the movie player view controller    
    [self presentModalViewController:mediaPlayer animated:YES];

    [mediaPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [mediaPlayer.moviePlayer play];
}
```

The notification handler is called and reaches the `Check go here` log. But it does not dismiss the modalViewController.
Anyone can help me?

Thank You

It happens on iOS 4.3 and iOs 5

Comment: I guess you checked if your function movieFinishedCallback: is called in case no internet connexion?

Comment: yep it is called. it prints out check Go here. but the the movieplayer not dismissed :(

Comment: Shouldn't it be [moviePlayer dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ? (I'm not sure)

Comment: nope, its not working. moviePlayer is a MPMoviePlayer. It does not have that method.

Comment: The solution is i just set animated to no when presentingModalViewController. It seems like it wants to dismiss while still animating.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still looking for the answer.
Per Apple doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MPMoviePlayerViewController

"To dismiss a modally presented movie player view controller, call the dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated method."